# Chrome Dev Tools claim that styles overrides themselves

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, development-environment

How should I understand following entries in Chrome Dev Tools:

[image]

Styles overrides... themselves (same file, same line, same style)?

Comment: What do those lines in `frontend.css` look like?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand your question correctly. These lines look _exactly_ like in example image. I.e. `ul.list {margin-top: 20px;}` and `.list {font-size: 0.8125em;}`.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean "Styles overrides... themselves?".

Comment: I thought, it is quite self explanatory, what do I mean. I was surprised to find out entry suggesting that any style is overridden (changed) by exactly the same style. Changing one thing to exactly the same things isn't a change or override for me so pictured entries looks like non-sense or at least confusing to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading the same CSS file twice.

Here is an image showing exactly what happens in your case:

[image]

This is exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Read basic usage rules of this site, please. Don't put an answer, if you don't answer anything actually. Put such questions as comments, please.

Comment: @trejer, this answer isn't a comment, it's an answer. You asked how you should understand those entries, and the answer answers that. I think you need to clarify exactly what your question is; what are you trying to understand from that screenshot?

Comment: @AndrewFerrier It is an answer... now. And thus I upvoted it and accepted. Before edit it was a mere comment [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30453180/1) if I'm loading CSS script twice. Such clarification requests should be expressed as comments only. After edit, when this answer become true statement (that I am loading my script twice and that is the cause of my problem) and full featured answer, I changed my vote and accepted it. Hope, that this explains all.